# Opening Window mobile 6 professional emulator

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, emulation, windows-mobile-6.1

I make a window mobile application using ms visual studio 2005 professional.

1. Could I run this application in emulator without installing Visual
   Studio?
2. If I run this in visual studio 2008 or 2010, is there any
   difference?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Microsoft Device Emulator 3.0 -- Standalone Release [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5352). In fact, it is the same emulator that MS starts from within Visual Studio and attaches a debugger to the emulator, so there should not be any different behavior.